# Microsoft LDAP schema case sensitive

Tags: ldap

Is it possible to force schema to be case sensitive?

I know that in IBM TDS it is how it set by default and to change that you need to set it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of an attribute (defined in the the schema) constrains the data types and structure of an attribute value. Comparisons (for example, case sensitivity) are not provided by the syntax but via separate matching rules. Some matching rules are case-sensitive, some are not.

LDAP-compliant servers support an extensible match filter that can be used to specify the matching rule to be used by the server if a specific type of comparison is required. For example, the filter:

```
(cn:caseExactMatch:=Darth Vader)
```

will evaluate to `true` if the `cn` attribute of an entry matches the case exactly.

In summary, attribute values are not global, nor are they case-sensitive or case-insensitive. An attribute type's value is constrained by the syntax, and matched by a matching rule.