# How to do a case-sensitive search on an LDAP server (with examples)

Tags: ldap, case-sensitive

Can someone please provide or point me to an example(s) of doing case sensitive searches on an LDAP server?

I have found some questions that point me in the right direction, e.g.
[Microsoft LDAP schema case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448822/microsoft-ldap-schema-case-sensitive)

However, when I try doing a search on a custom attribute in my directory, it doesn't seem to work for me.

e.g. `(CustomAttribute:caseExactMatch:=Foo)` does not match any entries, even though I know that they exist, i.e. if I search for `(CustomAttribute:=Foo)`, I get entries FOO, Foo and foo returned. (Note that this is a simplified/sanitized version of my actual search)

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any pointers or tips.

PS: I have read this Google search result: http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html

Which says:

> The above filter will match "User.0" but not "user.0". Some broken directory servers do not fully implement the LDAP standards and do not support this useful capability.

Perhaps my directory is one of these, or am I just messing up my search?

Comment: MS Active Directory is one of those servers that 'do not fully implement the LDAP standards'.